# Using xargs twice in one line for to fix subversion «!» status

Tags: svn, shell, status, xargs

I find the best solution for my problem here: [Howto fix subversion «!» status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389620/howto-fix-subversion-status)

But now, I just wish to write a small script to do that.

Like this:

```
svn status | grep '\!' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn revert

svn status | grep '\!' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn delete
```

But in one line.

Because, after the svn revert, "svn status | grep '!'" return no results. Rational.

I think that I found a solution: [Putting the data passed to xargs twice in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375905/putting-the-data-passed-to-xargs-twice-in-one-line) but I'm little rusty in English and command line isn't my strong skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
svn status | grep '\!' | awk '{print $2}' | tee list.$$ | xargs svn revert
xargs svn delete < list.$$
rm list.$$
```

The `tee` command is like a T pipe fitting; one copy of the output goes to each named file and another to standard output.    Here, I've named just one file.  This forces all the reverts to happen before any of the deletes.The name `list.$$` is a simple way of protecting the script from trampling on the files of other processes; there are programs like `mktemp` that can be used to create more secure, less predictable names.  OTOH, if you aren't running in hostile environments, it is unlikely to matter.  If you're being really careful, you'll create a `trap` to ensure the file is cleaned up:

```
tmp=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/list.$$
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

svn status | grep '\!' | awk '{print $2}' | tee $tmp | xargs svn revert
xargs svn delete < $tmp

rm $tmp
trap 0
```

There are other tricks that could be tried, but at least some of them don't guarantee the sequential operation.  For example, process substitution in `bash`:

```
svn status | grep '\!' | awk '{print $2}' | tee >(xargs svn revert) | xargs svn delete
```

Each file will be both reverted and deleted, but the sequencing is not predictable.

Comment: Work fine with trap. Just some errors to revert directory but the svn delete work after. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Both commands in one line. Note the complete loss of xargs. Not that xargs isn't wonderful, it is just not needed here.

```
x="$(svn status | grep '\!' | awk '{print $2}')"; svn revert "$x" && svn delete "$x" || echo "no svn delete $?"
```

Note that the **svn delete** will not run if the **svn revert** fails. The "no svn delete" indicates one of the svn commands failed.